# Getting "The underlying provider failed on Open" exception for Sybase database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sybase

I am working on application which uses Sybase database and entity framework for accessing database. I am trying to make application to open connection itself and close it. I created model using Sybase database file and now connecting to it to get data. But when I try to get data I get exception "The underlying provider failed to Open".

Here is my code.

```
var connectionString = metadata=res://*/SampleModel.csdl|res://*/SampleModel.ssdl|res://*/SampleModel.msl; + 
         provider=iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere; + 
         provider connection string="DBF=D:\SampleDatabase.db;UID=DBA;PWD=sql"
var dataContext = new SampleContext(connectionString);
var contacts = dataContext.Contacts; --> Here I get this exception.
```

Note: If I create a DSN in ODBC and use DSN instead of giving filename it gives me Not connected to a database exception. If I open this connection and do not close it, then it works fine. But I don't want to create DSN entry and open it manually. I want my program to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There was problem with my version of Sybase. I was using 3840 build of Sybase 12. I removed it and installed 3769 version and it worked fine. On different forums I found out that latest (3840) is having problems.